# JS Dom - Different between appendChild() vs Add()

Tags: javascript, dom

```
 let option = document.createElement('option');
     option.className = "dropdown-item"
     option.innerText = username;
     option.setAttribute('data-value',results[username]);
     userDropdown[item].add(option);
```

At some point I come across two similar situations where - at first I add child element using parent.add(child) in dropdown selection which has option children and it worked fine. Another place I have bootstrap drop down with anchor element as child but here parent.add(child) no longer works and threw this error `TypeError: userDropdown[item].add is not a function`.Only appendChild works as such below

```
 let option = document.createElement('a');
     option.className = "dropdown-item"
     option.innerText = username;
     option.setAttribute('data-value',results[username]);
     userDropdown[item].appendChild(option);
```

When I do search on the web I dont find any clear answer on how these two are different.Anyone can pls explain it to me?

Comment: there is no such thing as "add" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node you might confuse it with jquery add https://api.jquery.com/add/

Comment: @GottZ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/add

Comment: The type you're calling `add` on matters: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/add. Also: "no longer works" isn't diagnostic--you got a console error message, which states it's not a function, which it isn't on a non-select element. When asking questions it's best to include all relevant information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I add child element using parent.add(child) in dropdown selection

This works because you are invoking the [`HTMLSelectElement#add`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/add) method. It exists only on [`<select>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement) elements, not on all nodes, unlike [`Node#appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).

```js
const selectEl = document.createElement("select");
const divEl = document.createElement("div");
const spanEl = document.createElement("span");
const bodyEl = document.body;

console.log("You can .add to a <select> :", "add" in selectEl);
console.log("You can .add to a <div>    :", "add" in divEl);
console.log("You can .add to a <span>   :", "add" in spanEl);
console.log("You can .add to a <body>   :", "add" in bodyEl);
```